# count of false gives 1 and if of an empty array gives false. why?

Tags: php

I have a function which returns only one row as array.

I give a query as a parameter which will exactly gives only one row.

```
function getFields($query)
{
    $t =& get_instance(); 
    $ret = $t->db->query($query);
    if(!$ret)return false;
    else if(!$ret->num_rows()) return array();
    else return $ret->row_array();
}
$ret = getFields('query string');
```

What i thought was ...

1. if there is an error then i can check it like if(!$res)//echo error
2. if it is empty i can check it like if(!count($res))// no rows
3. else i assume that there is a row and continue the process...

BUT

1. when there is an error false is returned. In if(count($ret)) gives 1.
2. If($ret) conditions fails (gives false) if i return as empty array.

//

```
$ret = getFields('query string');
if(!$fes)jerror('status,0,msg,dberror');        
if(!count($fes))jerror('status,1,msg,no rows');     
// continue execution when there atleast one row.
```

this code is called using ajax. so i return a json response.

why count gives 1 and if empty array gives false.

**i just wanted to code with logical conditions instead of giving more relations conditions. just to reduce code.**

Where can i get all these BUGGING stuff of php so that i can make sure i should not end up making logical errors like the above.

> BUGGING - in the above sentence
>   bugging i referred as not a bug but
>   things bugs us. things which makes us
>   logical errors.

---

---

*I edited this following code to include the following meanwhile i got this as the reply by https://stackoverflow.com/users/451672/andrew-dunn*

i can do it like this but still i want to know why for the above explanation

```
if($fes===false)jerror();
if(!$fes)jsuccess('status,4');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"why count gives 1" - see http://docs.php.net/count:

> If var is not an array [...] 1 will be returned.

"and if empty array gives false." - see http://docs.php.net/language.types.boolean#language.types.boolean.casting:

> When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE: 
> [...]
>
> - an array with zero elements

Comment: aahh... am i too lazy to refer the document... may be some times like this time. hhhmm yes... thanks. i am doing a little analysis with the above and will get back...

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just check if `$ret === false` first?

Comment: i was about to edit my post to include that and found your reply.

Comment: this is one good suggestion for a question above. nice. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If `$myVariable` is not array, but empty, then

```
$count = count($myVariable);
```

gives `1`.

For this situation I check whether the variable is "array" or "bool(false)". If output is array, I use count, if it isn't an array I set number to zero.

```
if (is_array($myVariable)) {
    $count = count($myVariable);
} else {
    $count = 0;
}
```