# Why count(false) return 1?

Tags: php, count

Do you know why `<?= count(false) ?>` returns `1`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [count of false gives 1 and if of an empty array gives false. why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776882/count-of-false-gives-1-and-if-of-an-empty-array-gives-false-why)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's specified behavior:

> If var is not an array or an object with implemented Countable
>   interface, 1 will be returned.

According to http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

Comment: ...you beat me by 5 seconds, so i'll just give you the +1

Comment: how to get 0 from count if there is not an array??

Comment: @Ritesh how about `$count = $var != false ? count($var) : 0;`?

Answer (score 10):

Because `false` is also a value and if the count() does not get array but a valid variable it returns `true` which is `1`.

```
$result = count(null);
// $result == 0

$result = count(false);
// $result == 1
```

Comment: "Random" comment: it's like how if(0) returns false and if(-1) returns true.

Comment: You're close: it doesn't return `true`. `count` is expecting an array and if `var` isn't one, it gets cast into an array. Since `false` is a valid value, it gets cast to an array with one element: an element with the the value `false`. http://justinsomnia.org/2007/12/in-php-countfalse-returns-1/

Answer (score 3):

A nice way to remember this in your mind:

- count(false) is basically the same as:
- count ("one boolean"), and therefore there are "ONE" booleans as result.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like PHP is preventing one from using `count()` to determine if an element is an array or an object. They have dedicated functions for this (`is_array()`, `is_object()`) and it may be tempting to naively use `count()` and check for a `false` condition to determine array or object. Instead, PHP makes non-objects, non-arrays return `1` (which is truthy) so that this method cannot be be naively used in this way (since `0` is a valid, falsy result for an empty array/object).

This may be the why behind the choice of value to be returned by the function in the situation you're describing.

Comment: He's not trying to determine if it's an array or object, he's trying to determine the length of the array and questioning why a 0-record or non-existent array is still returning 1.