# php Imap_search count always returns 1 when there is no messages in mail account

Tags: php, imap, gmail-imap

When my mail account has some messages matching the search criteria it gives the correct count. But whenever there is no messages(0 number of messages) as per the searching criteria that time also it returns the count as '1'..here is my code..Give me suggestions..

```
$imap = imap_open("{mail.amazepixels.com}INBOX", "mail_id", "password")
  or die("can't connect: " . imap_last_error());

$rec = imap_search($imap, 'ON "22 May 2017"');
$rec_count = count($rec);

$ans = imap_search($imap, 'UNANSWERED ON "22 May 2017"');
$ans_count = count($ans);

$seen = imap_search($imap, 'UNSEEN ON "22 May 2017"');
$seen_count = count($seen);

echo $rec_count."-".$ans_count."-".$seen_count;exit;
```

I just have given the future date..it returns the count `1` always..

Comment: it's because `imap_search()` returns `false` if no messages are found and `count(false) == 1`. Change it to: `$ans_count = $ans ? count($ans) : 0;` and it should work.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson  is right here.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thank so much ..nice work..I have an one doubt..the message_id is null only  for inbox messages getting from gmail accounts..U have any comments?

Comment: I don't know anything about that, though. You should make another question for that issue, if you can't find the answer here. Btw, I wrote an answer. Feel free to mark it as accepted if it worked for you.

Comment: @Magnus ..My pleasure..I  did..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`imap_search()` returns `false` if no messages are found and `count(false) == 1`.

You can fix it by changing it to:

```
$ans_count = $ans ? count($ans) : 0;
```

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-search.php):

> *Return FALSE if it does not understand the search criteria or no messages have been found.*

Here's a post about the count issue: [Why count(false) return 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15327508/why-countfalse-return-1)