# PHP if null or false return empty array by default?

Tags: php

Why this line of code does not work in php like as in JS:

```
$id = [];

$id = null || [];

if (count($id)) {
  echo 'd';
}
```

Why `$id` still is null instead empty array `[]`? Therefore `count()` gives an error.

Comment: Because PHP and JS are completely different languages based on completely different coding models.

Comment: So it write in php in short form??

Comment: i think you mean this `$id = null ?? [];`

Comment: What does it mean double `??`?

Comment: Note that `$id` is assigned `false` not `null`.  See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15327508/why-countfalse-return-1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In PHP, [logical operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) like `||` always return a boolean, even if given a non-boolean output.

So your statement is evaluated as "is either `null` or `[]` truthy?" Since both `null` and an empty array evaluate to false, the result is boolean `false`.

There are however two operators which would do something similar to JS's `||`:

- `$a ?: $b` is short-hand for `$a ? $a : $b`; in other words, it evaluates to `$a` if it's "truthy", or `$b` if not (this is documented along with [the ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) for which it is a short-hand)
- `$a ?? $b` is similar, but checks for `null` rather than "truthiness"; it's equivalent to `isset($a) ? $a : $b` (this is called the [null-coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce))

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php

// PHP < 7
$id = isset($id) ? $id : [];

// PHP >= 7
$id = $id ?? [];

// PHP >= 7.4
$id ??= [];
```

As of PHP 7 and above
[Null Coalesce Operator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary)
[Another helpful link](https://stitcher.io/blog/shorthand-comparisons-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

**Watch out!**

I find PHP's handling of `empty` to be highly questionable:

- `empty($unsetVar)` == true (fabulous, no need to check `isset` as warning is suppressed!)
- `empty(null)` == true
- `empty('')` == true

All fine, until we get to this nonsense:

- `empty(false)` == true. *Wait, WHAT???*

You've **GOT** to be kidding me. In no world should `false` be taken to mean the same thing as no value at all!  There's nothing "empty" about a false assertion. And due to this logical fallacy, you cannot use `empty` to check ANY variable that might have a **VALUE** of `false`.

In my projects, I use a static method:

```php
public static function hasValue($value) {
    return isset($value) && !is_null($value) && $value !== '';
}
```

Of course, using this method, I no longer get the free warning suppression provided by `empty`, so now I'm also forced to remember to call the method above with the notice/warning suppression operator `@`:

```php
if(self::hasValue(@$possiblyUnsetVar)) {}
```

Very frustrating.