# Why the count function returns 1 for false and 0 for NULL

Tags: php, count

I was going through the count function in php. Here, http://docs.php.net/count I have not got why the count function returns 1 for false and 0 for NULL

```
<?php

  $result = count(null);
  // $result == 0

  $result = count(false);
  // $result == 1
?>
```

This answer ([count of false gives 1 and if of an empty array gives false. why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776882/count-of-false-gives-1-and-if-of-an-empty-array-gives-false-why)) doesn't tell what I'm searching for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If var is not an array or an object with implemented Countable interface, 1 will be returned.

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

Comment: The referenced page also states `NULL` returns 0.  Problem solved.

Comment: +1 Yeps: `Returns the number of elements in array_or_countable. If the parameter is not an array or not an object with implemented Countable interface, 1 will be returned. There is one exception, if array_or_countable is NULL, 0 will be returned.`

Answer (score 1):

From the [PHP doc](http://docs.php.net/count):

> There is one exception, if array_or_countable is NULL, 0 will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

`count()` may return 0 for a variable that isn't set, but it may also return 0 for a variable that has been initialized with an empty array. Use isset() to test if a variable is set.

```
    $b[0]  = 7;
    $b[5]  = 9;
    $b[10] = 11;
    $result = count($b);
    // $result == 3

    $result = count(null);
    // $result == 0

    $result = count(false);
    // $result == 1
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php